# Combinatorics - Choose Any Marble Exactly 4 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Suppose a bag contains 10 marbles all uniquely distinct from one another and we are to pick 1 marble out of the bag a time 10 times with replacement.

What are the odds that you pick the same marble 4 times? 3 times? 2 times? Every marble exactly once?

---

I'm going to focus on the P(4) case which is the probability that we pick any marble exactly 4 times.

I think what is tripping me up is the end part of eliminating special cases.

I know for reference that unordered sampling with replacement there are ${n+k-1\choose k} = {10+10-1\choose 10} = {19\choose 10}\ = 92, 378$ total combinations.

How I was trying to solve it was take the probability of getting the same marble 4 times is $\frac{1}{10} ^4 * 10$ (since there are 10 marbles that could be repeated 4 times. There are then $_{10}C_4$ combinations for getting 4 of the same marble so ${10\choose 4} = 210 $ total combinations with 4 the same.

Then I was just going to multiply by  $\frac{9}{10} ^6$ for .001*210*.531441 = 11.16 but I realize that out of the 6 remaining marbles I can't pick the same one more than 4 times for this to be truly accurate. And this method doesn't seem to apply correctly for P(3) and P(2) so I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You say "exactly once is easy to solve" but the argument that follows is not persuasive.  What do you think the answer is in that case?

Comment: Isn't supposed to be persuasive, I feel like I got lost and not sure where.

Comment: So I'd start with the case in which every marble is chosen exactly once.

Comment: Note:  I don't even understand what you mean by $P(4)$.  Would $A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B$ count for that event?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda throwing that first case away because there is only 1 way without order you can pick every marble once. So it's 1/92,378. for your P(4) question I would say no, I'm looking for the probability that a single marble is picked exactly 4 times, not at least 4 times.

Comment: There are $10!$ equiprobable ways to choose each marble exactly once, and $10^{10}$ equiprobable ways to draw $10$ marbles....so the probability of the "exactly once" case is $\frac {10!}{10^{10}}=\frac {9!}{10^9}$.

Comment: As to $P(4)$ I think you should edit your post to indicate exactly what you mean.  Would $A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C$ count, for instance?  What about $A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C$?

Comment: I see what was tripping me up now on that regarding all the same, I do have to consider them ordered for the probabilities to all stay equal for each case. There is some ambiguity in the question that I'm trying to decide how to argue, whether A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B counts or not. My guess is it should be answered with the view of the the probability of the marble picked the most times was exactly 4. Then A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C would count, but would have to be de-duped from the combinations.

Comment: Well, that makes sense (and you should edit to reflect that).  I'd go case by case. Look at the  $10-$tuples  $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_{10})$ which sum to $10$ and for which $a_i≤4$ for all $i$.  Try to describe all the possible patterns (not too bad) and do the count that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order does matter here. If you want every element of your probability space to be equally likely, you need to count ordered sequences, not unordered ones. For example, the probability of observing the same marble 10 times is **not** the same as the chance of observing a particular marble nine times and a different one once. The former has probability $\frac{1}{10^{10}}$, the latter $\binom{10}1 \cdot \frac1{10^{10}}$.

---

I think you need to do inclusion-exclusion to answer this. Number the marbles 1 to 10, and for each $i$, find the probability of choosing marble $i$ four times. There are $\binom{10}4$ ways to choose which times you draw the $i$, then $9^6$ ways to choose the other marbles. Since there are $10$ choices for $i$, it seems like the probabability would be 
$$
10\cdot \frac{\binom{10}49^6}{10^{10}}
$$

However, sequence which have two marbles $i$ and $j$ both appearing four times are double counted by the above expression. We must subtract these out, resulting in 
$$
10\cdot \frac{\binom{10}49^6}{10^{10}}-\binom{10}{2}\frac{\binom{10}4\binom{6}48^2}{10^{10}}
$$

Comment: Thanks, you're right I was stuck thinking unordered would be fine. I see the flaw in my initial thinking. So in the smaller cases the subtraction element becomes far more complex, no? In P(3) i have to remove the chance that two marbles could appear 3 times?

Comment: And this is more to the ambiguity in the question, but in your case what about if j appears 5 times? I'm thinking the way to properly answer the somewhat ambiguous question would be the probability that the marble selected the most often was selected exactly 4 times, then you'd just have to de-dupe the case of two appearing 4 times like you did above.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that for P(3) you would have to add back in the triple intersections. P(2) is even worse; you need to go all the way to the 5-way intersections.

Comment: If j appears 5 times, it does not need to be subtracted out, since it was not counted in the first place.

Comment: Actually, before the subtraction portion we had the same answer 11.16%. Why would that still work out if order did actually matter, is it just for the subtraction portion?